# How to unit test method which gets data from database and saves to a file is saving the correct data

Tags: c#, unit-testing

Here is my code:

```
public void GenerateCarDetailsFile(IList<int> carIds, string location)
{

   var cars = Uow.Query<Car>().Where(x => carIds.Contains(x.Id));

   var stringWriter = new StringWriter();

   stringWriter.WriteLine("Make, Model, Year");

   foreach(var car in cars)
   {
     stringWriter.WriteLine("{0},{1},{2}", car.Make, car.Model, car.Year);
   }

   SaveToFile(stringWriter, location);
}

public void SaveToFile(StringWriter stringWriter, string location)
{
   var bytes = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(stringWriter.ToString());
   var file = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(location);
   file.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
   file.Close();
}
```

So I'm getting a bunch of cars from the database. Writing them to a stringWriter then saving them to a file.

My question is how to unit test that the right info is getting saved to the file. Is this untestable? Is it more of an integration test?

I can't imagine how to do it because both methods return void.

Answer (score 2):

You can test if it saves the correct data by reading the saved file back and parsing it. If you can parse the data correctly, it should be "saved correctly". If you're asking whether the code actually saves a file to disk, that is a unit test of the FileStream class, not your class.

It would be easier to test the *behaviour* of your class by using a mocking library though. Here's a comparison of three frameworks that seems to be popular in the C# community; [Rhino Mocks vs Moq vs NSubstitute](http://dennis-nerush.blogspot.se/2012/10/rhino-mocks-vs-moq-vs-nsubstitute.html). I would also recommend [NUnit](http://www.nunit.org/) (available with nuget as well) simply because it's a nice test framework.

When using a mocking framework, you create a "fake" object that your class can use. This also means that you should use dependency injection (i.e. inject a dependency to your class). The dependencies for your class seems to be a database access class, and a file access class. By passing those to your class, you are also following the [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle), in simple terms saying that one class should only know one thing. (It should not know how to access a database *and* how to access a file for instance)

Simply create two interfaces for what you need, `IDatabaseRepository` and `IFileStorage` or something along those lines. Then inject instances of those to your class. When you are creating unit tests, these are easily mocked. Using Rhino mocks for instance, a unit test can look along the lines of this.

```
public interface IDatabaseProvider {
    IEnumerable<Car> GetCars();
}

public interface IFileStorage {
    string ReadText(string filepath);
    void SaveText(string filepath, string content);
}

public class MyClass {
    private readonly IDatabaseProvider dataProvider;
    private readonly IFileStorage storage;

    public MyClass(IDatabaseProvider dataProvider, IFileStorage storage) {
        this.dataProvider = dataProvider;
        this.storage = storage;
    }

    public void GenerateCarDetailsFile(IList<int> carIds, string location) {
        var cars = dataProvider.GetCars().Query<Car>().Where(x => carIds.Contains(x.Id));
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.AppendLine("Make, Model, Year");

        foreach(var car in cars) {
            builder.WriteLine("{0},{1},{2}", car.Make, car.Model, car.Year);
        }

        storage.SaveText(location, builder.ToString());
    }
}

[Test]
public void GenerateCarDetailsSavesFile() {
    // Arrange
    var databaseReturnValue = new List<Car> { new Car() { Make = "ma", Model = "mo", Year = 1900 };
    var location = "testpath.ext";
    var ids = new List<int> { 1, 3, 6 };
    var expectedOutput = "Make, Model, Year\r\nma,mo,1900";

    var database = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IDatabaseProvider>();
    var storage = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IFileStorage>();

    database
       .Stub(m => m.GetCars())
       .Return(databaseReturnValue);
    storage
       .Expect(m => m.SaveText(Arg<string>.Is.Equal(location),
                               Arg<string>.Is.Equal(expectedOutput)));

    MyClass testee = new MyClass(database, storage);

    // Act
    testee.GenerateCarDetailsFile(ids, location);

    // Assert
    storage.VerifyAllExpectations();
}
```

You are testing the behaviour of your class, and the fact that it should call `SaveText` on the `IFileStorage` dependency. By using dependency injection and abstracting all auxiliary systems, you can create tests that won't fail because a database is not accessible or the file system is full (note that those events could be another unit test).

You will also create classes that are more portable. When moving this to another platform that has another way of accessing the file system (`File` vs `StorageFile` in .NET vs Windows Store for instance) you simply create a platform specific `IFileStorage` implementation.

So, don't test the behaviour of other classes. Test the behaviour of your class in regards to its dependencies instead. Then use mocks to setup a behaviour of those dependencies that work the same inbetween tests.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to `mock` the data access object using a mocking framework. That way you can unit test it without being dependent on th actual database contents, or even needing a database connection.

Furthermore, i would split the "retrieval part" and the "saving part" of your first method, so you can test those parts individually:

```
public StringWriter GenerateCarDetails(IList<int> carIds)
{

   var cars = Uow.Query<Car>().Where(x => carIds.Contains(x.Id));

   var stringWriter = new StringWriter();

   stringWriter.WriteLine("Make, Model, Year");

   foreach(var car in cars)
   {
     stringWriter.WriteLine("{0},{1},{2}", car.Make, car.Model, car.Year);
   }

   return stringWriter;
}

public void SaveToFile(StringWriter stringWriter, string location)
{
   var bytes = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(stringWriter.ToString());
   var file = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(location);
   file.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
   file.Close();
}
```

or even like so:

```
public IEnumerable<Car> LoadCarDetails(IList<int> carIds)
{
   var cars = Uow.Query<Car>().Where(x => carIds.Contains(x.Id));
   return cars;
}

public StringWriter ConvertCarListToStrings(IEnumerable<Car> cars)
{
   var stringWriter = new StringWriter();

   stringWriter.WriteLine("Make, Model, Year");

   foreach(var car in cars)
   {
     stringWriter.WriteLine("{0},{1},{2}", car.Make, car.Model, car.Year);
   }

   return stringWriter;
}

public void SaveToFile(StringWriter stringWriter, string location)
{
   var bytes = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(stringWriter.ToString());
   var file = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(location);
   file.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
   file.Close();
}
```

so you can at least test `ConvertCarListToStrings` with known data.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is **[Mocking with Dependency Injection](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35881/Simplified-Mocking-with-Dependency-Injection-for-U)**.
This way your'e not dependent on anything.
Pure logic testing.

Answer (score 0):

Testing this entire process is more of an integration test. What has worked for me is to have the test create a test database, load some sample data into it, then pass the database connection (or ORM representation) to the class containing your query.

After calling `GenerateCarDetailsFile` you can have the test load the file (from the passed in location) and make sure it looks right. Then finally have the test clean up after itself to delete the file and test database.

Another options is to use a good mocking/substitution framework to mock either the DB and/or the File IO. My personal favorite is `NSubstitute` (http://nsubstitute.github.io/)

Answer (score 0):

You may create a specialized interface `IDataProvider` with methods like `GetCarsById(IEnumerable<int> ids)`. Then move all queries to the implementation of the interface. Get the implementation injected where it is required and create mock implementation for testing.